# Search Strings (bunch of words seperated by comma) in a column SQL

Tags: sql, .net, select

I have a column in a table with value "Apple, Ball, Cat, Dog"

Now I have a variable with value "Ball, Dog, Cat"

1. How can I get the row that contains either "ball" or "Dog" or "Cat" (not necessarily in the same sequence as in table column)
2. How can I get the row that contains either "ball" and "Dog" and "Cat" (not necessarily in the same sequence as in table column)

Help is greatly appreciated. I tried "contains" and like. But SQL fails if the variable contains two words Ex: "Black Cat".

Comment: Fix your data structure so you have four rows, instead of string with the values munged together.

Comment: If you set your columns up to store multiple values, expect to fight with that data every time you need to get information back out. Find a tutorial on SQL and databases and work your way through it. There are some extremely valuable lessons you haven't gotten yet.

Comment: The number of columns are not same all the time. the column values are generated from multi select checkbox. In this case should I process for each checkbox, add a new row ? @gordon-linoff

Answer (score 0):

in sql you should be able to do this:

```
select * 
from Table_Name
Where Column_Name like '%Dog%' 
  or Column_Name like '%Cat%'
  or Column_Name like '%Ball%'
```

and it will select the rows where the column contains dog, ball, or cat, you may need to set a

```
select distinct *
...
```

if you only one each row to be returned once.

Comment: I have variable dim sq as string = "Cat, Ball, Dog"
how can i break the string "sq" and do what you mentioned above ?

Comment: See string.split.  I assume you're asking how to break apart a string from a VB.Net app...?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: yes i am asking to split the string by "," and build query like 
select * 
from Table_Name
Where Column_Name like '%Dog%' 
  or Column_Name like '%Cat%'
  or Column_Name like '%Ball%'
@cobolstinks

Comment: ok sounds good, you should be able to do that after viewing that msdn link.